# How to run the logTruthiness function

Tags: javascript, truthiness

This code given below is supposed to evaluate if a value coerces to true or false. How does this work? for example if I want to know if a string- "my string" will be coereced to true or false, how do I use the to determine that?

I have tried to replace val in the code below with "my string" everywhere val shows up

```
function logTruthiness (val) {
if (val) {
    console.log("Truthy!");
} else {
    console.log("Falsy.");
}
}


function logTruthiness ("my string") {
if ("my string") {
    console.log("Truthy!");
} else {
    console.log("Falsy.");
}
}
```

error 
    function logTruthiness ("my string") {
SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: `val` is a variable, so you don't want to replace it in the function. Call the function like so: `logTruthiness("my string")`

Comment: You'd call it like this: `logTruthiness("my string")`

Answer (score 0):

You could submit a value directly to it:

```
logTruthiness("my string");
```

You could also submit a variable:

```
let str = "my string";
logTruthiness(str);
```

But you don't want to change the function declaration itself (which is what you did by trying to modify the parameter to a pre-defined string)

Comment: et myarr = [true, false,  "my string", null, NaN, [], {} ]

Comment: if I want to find out if the eleemnts of this array coerce to true or false, would that be more complicated to do?

Comment: You'd need to run through each element and test them one by one. It's not that much more complicated, but you do have to run through your array. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured out the answer after reading about functions.
So the function is kind of chain of commands that will be executed, one has to provide the value after declaring the function.
Thanks for the patience.